# Choosing only the first half of a year in SOQL

Tags: soql

I am trying to select only the first six months of a year in a SOQL statement.

What I have so far is,

```
WHERE (CALENDAR_QUARTER(CreatedDate) = 1 OR CALENDAR_QUARTER(CreatedDate) = 2)
```

While it does the job, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to choose those dates, as I am really concerned with the speed.

I have thought about using the `IN` statement, but I am not sure where to being with that. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Speed as in "how quickly my code finishes executing", or speed as in "how much of the CPU limit does it use"? In either situation, the first thing you need to do is _take measurements, and define for yourself how slow/fast/high/low/whatever is unacceptable_. If you don't know what criteria you should be using and/or the current performance isn't causing an issue, that's a sign that it's "efficient enough" and that you'd be wasting time with premature/micro optimization.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is definitely processing that I'd keep as part of the SOQL instead of trying to do it in Apex. From the governor limit documentation, `Operations that don't consume application server CPU time aren't counted toward CPU time. For example, the portion of execution time spent in the database for DML, SOQL, and SOSL isn't counted`. About the only suggestion I can make here is to change your filter to `CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) < 7`, the main benefit of which is "it's less typing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, the Query Optimizer will fix this for you. You don't need to worry about which form to use. That said, you can reduce the length of code to make it more legible (at least, in my opinion):

```
WHERE CALENDAR_QUARTER(CreatedDate) IN (1,2)
```

This should have absolutely zero impact on either query performance, CPU time, etc, but makes it easier to read, especially if you start adding more conditions in the future.